# CSS/Wordpress How to manage spaces for content

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is CSS of the website and it is getting spaces on the both left and right side before content. can anybody tell me how should I update it, so it can manage left side and right side space on the website.

```
.site {
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .site-content {
        float: left;
        width: 65.104166667%;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: You should provide a working example. The description and code you have provided don't provide us enough information to understand what the issue actually is or how to provide a solution.

Comment: i have edited post with image @hungerstar

Answer (score 0):

Its .container what controls the width of your content after the header

```
 .container{
    // css code here controls the width of your content-sidebar
    //for example: 'width: 100%;'
    }
```

after that you might want to increase your #primary width aswell to fix placement.

```
#primary{
// something like width:78.5%
}
```